# iOS 9 Push Notifications dyld`dyld_fatal_error:

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am receiving an error for push notifications while running on my iOS device.
iOS version is 9.In Xcode also my deployment target is set to 9.0  Below is my AppDelegate code and also I have attached the snapshot of error..Kindly help

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    var token = ""
    for i in 0..<deviceToken.count {
        token = token + String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [deviceToken[i]])
    }
    print("Registration succeeded! Token: ", token)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("APNs registration failed: \(error)")
}
func showAlertAppDelegate(title: String,message : String,buttonTitle: String,window: UIWindow){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: buttonTitle, style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    window.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDSmy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `token` to `String` conversion with the following line:

```
let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
```

I suggest you to use Exception breakpoints to get more info about error. Here is [a link](https://www.natashatherobot.com/xcode-debugging-user-breakpoints/) how to use it.